# Open suse adding repository

Tags: download, repository, suse, terminator

Hi I'm trying to add repository to install Termintor on my linux machine (SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP3). However after running this command

```
sudo zypper -v addrepo https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/openSUSE:Factory/standard/openSUSE:Factory.repo
```

I get 503 error.

```
 Download (curl) error for 'https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/openSUSE:Factory/standard/openSUSE:Factory.repo':
Error code: HTTP response: 0
Error message: The requested URL returned error: 503
```

Apparently the source is not available. Is there a way to find the current repo for installing Terminator via zypper?

Answer (score 1):

The correct repository for SLE12 is:

```
sudo zypper addrepo https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/X11:/terminals/SLE_12/X11:terminals.repo
```

You can find all the available SUSE builds for 'Terminator' here: https://software.opensuse.org/package/terminator